# ==1 still returning NaN values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

This is my first question and i'm relatively new to all this so sorry in advance if it is stupid, but i've spent quite a bit of time searching and trying dif solutions.

I have a df of track data and their weekly rankings.  For weeks where tracks went unranked, the data is 'NaN'.

```
pv = df.pivot_table(df, index=['track'])
pv2 = pv.fillna(100)
pv2[pv2 == 1]
```

My question is, why is it still returning NaN in pv2 after the NaN is filled to '100'?  I haven't bee able how to get rid of the NaN and for instance, return all tracks that were 1st or 10th (for all weeks).  By the nature of the data, some columns will have 1's and NaN, other will have NaN but no 1's.  Most columns are a combo of NaN and range between 1 < 100.

I've tried to create another pv table (with dif indexes, making it so only the weeks are the columns, and only int64 as the dtype), changing dtypes, to no avail.  I think i may be looking at it the wrong way, as i'm quite new to all this...

Comment: Can you add sample of your data, 5-6 rows and desired output?

Comment: And welcome to StackOverflow. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you!  Trying to find the best way to give a sample of the data, its from a large cvs file full of float64 int64 strings, everything really (its a cvs of the billboard top 100 from a few years back)  I think this is the root of my issue, some rows(tracks) i want returned by default will have NaN's in them, but there are others that aren't '#1' still being returned (including the NaN's).  The way i have it structured may be the issue; i need to find some data to post

Comment: Ok, no problem. I try edit my answer with my sample. Then you can use it as template.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  yeah i've realized the problem is that I can't get the return i have in mind because of the structure of the df ( i need to make a new pv table to change this)

Comment: Hmmm, I think the best is working with small sample of data, verify solution and then apply it to big file. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply mask to dataframe, you get `NaN` where values are `False`:

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
a,1,227,2.33,15.7,158,149,158
b,2,1,231,1.3,15.9,145,1
c,0,228,23.3,1.57,1,145,153
d,7,227,2.31,15.6,159,149,1"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
print df
   a  b    c       d      e      f    g    h
0  a  1  227    2.33  15.70  158.0  149  158
1  b  2    1  231.00   1.30   15.9  145    1
2  c  0  228   23.30   1.57    1.0  145  153
3  d  7  227    2.31  15.60  159.0  149    1

print df == 1
       a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h
0  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False  False   True
2  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True

print df[df == 1]
     a    b    c   d   e    f   g    h
0  NaN  1.0  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN NaN  NaN NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN  1.0
```

Comment: I add sample of my data, please check it and change it. :)

Comment: let me ask you this: in your final block there, is there a easy way to flip the table ( having 0, 1, 2, 3 as columns, and a, b, , etc as rows)?

Comment: would that be a transpose? or; do i have to manually make a new pivot and just index all the columns and place them as rows instead?

Comment: Transposing uis very easy - use `print df.T`

Comment: haha, aw man you're awesome!  i feel like an idiot but that shined a bright light on the problem I was having, thank you so much!  The issue was that I couldn't 'get rid' of some/all NaNs because of the way i had that pv structured (they were inherently in the columns, so they couldn't 'go away' from rows

once again thank you!